# update table rows by just clicking on them

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have created an edit page which shows previously added data by running while loop.

Those data has been in table format and in input field. Now, i want to give update query to each record. After resetting data i am getting same value in every row in SQL.

Can anyone give me the solution for getting update for each rows.

[image]

---

Here is my code

```
    <form action="edit_item.php" method="post">
             <h3> Add New Item</h3>

            <div class="vali-form">
           <input type="hidden" name="i_id" value="<?php echo $i_id; ?>" placeholder="Enter item no." required="">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group1 form-last">
              <label class="control-label">Item No.</label>
              <input type="text" name="i_no" value="<?php echo $i_no ?>" placeholder="Enter item no." required="" readonly>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-6 form-group1 form-last">
              <label class="control-label">Item Name.</label>
              <input type="text" name="i_name" value="<?php echo $i_name ?>" placeholder="Enter item name" required="">
            </div>
           <div class="clearfix"> </div>
           </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 form-group1 form-last">
         <div class="table-responsive">

   <table  ID="tblPets" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">  

  <thead>  

        <tr>  

            <th><center>Row material Name</center></th> 
            <th><center>Description</center></th> 

            <th><center>Qty.</center></th> 

            <th><center>Rate</center></th> 

            <th><center><INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tblPets')" VALUE="Add Row"></center></th>  



        </tr>  
        </thead>
         <?php while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($run1))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        {  
        $r_id=$row1[0];
        $r_item_id=$row1[2];
        $r_name=$row1[3];
        $r_qty=$row1[4];
        $r_rate=$row1[5];

        ?>
         <tbody>

        <tr>  

            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_name[]" value="<?php echo $r_name ?>" PLACEHOLDER="Name"></th> 
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_desc[]" value="" PLACEHOLDER="description" ></th> 

            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_qty[]" value="<?php echo $r_qty ?>" PLACEHOLDER="QTY" ONINPUT="calculate()" ></th> 

            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_RATE[]" value="<?php echo $r_rate ?>" PLACEHOLDER="rate" ONINPUT="calculate()"></th> 
            <th></th>  

        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
                               </table>


  </div></div>


            <div class="vali-form">

            <div class="col-md-6 form-group1 form-last">
              <label class="control-label">Qty.</label>
              <input type="text" name="i_qty" value="<?php echo $i_qty ?>" placeholder="Enter Qty" required="">
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6 form-group1 form-last">
              <label class="control-label">Rate.</label>
              <input type="text" name="i_rate" value="<?php echo $i_rate ?>" placeholder="Enter rate" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
              <button type="submit" name="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
            </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
          </div>

        </form>
```

here is mysql query for update

```
    if(isset($_POST['Reset'])){
$item_id=$_POST['i_id'];
$item_no=$_POST['i_no'];
$item_name=$_POST['i_name'];
$item_qty=$_POST['i_qty'];
$item_rate=$_POST['i_rate'];

$update_item="UPDATE tbl_item_mstr SET itm_name='$item_name', itm_qty='$item_qty', itm_rate='$item_rate' WHERE itm_id='$item_id' ";

$q1=mysqli_query($dbcon,$update_item); 


if($q1)
{
 //header('Location: ../item_master.php');
}
if (!empty($_POST['r_name']) && !empty($_POST['r_qty']) && !empty($_POST['r_RATE']) && is_array($_POST['r_name']) && is_array($_POST['r_qty']) && is_array($_POST['r_RATE']) && count($_POST['r_name']) === count($_POST['r_qty']))  {



    $user = $_SESSION['email'];
    $name_array = $_POST['r_name'];
    $qty_array = $_POST['r_qty'];
    $rate_array = $_POST['r_RATE'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name_array[$i]);
        $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($qty_array[$i]);
        $rate = mysql_real_escape_string($rate_array[$i]);

        $update_item="UPDATE tbl_row_material SET rm_user_id='$user', rm_name='$name', rm_qty='$qty', rm_rate='$rate' WHERE rm_item_id='$item_no' ";
        $r=mysqli_query($dbcon,$update_item);

         if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$update_item))  
    {  

     header('Location: ../item_master.php');

    } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: can tell what error you are getting

Comment: if u see picture which i hv posted now it shows two table rows..when i update both of them it willl get same value for both rows since i actually given diffrent updates for each

Comment: `$item_no` is not defined.

Comment: is there is problem with the update ??

Comment: $item_no is defined but i hvnt posted that part to post

Comment: post that part of the code also

Comment: Please post coherent code. How can we help, otherwise? Also please note that `!empty()` return True even when an array has only one value: so - if one of the `<input>` is empty - the query is executed anyway. to check if all `<input>` are filled, you have to move the check inside `for` loop

Comment: @fusion and Arun i have edited post plz check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to update multiple row at the same time

```
    <?php while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($run1))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        {  
        $r_id=$row1[0];
        $r_item_id=$row1[2];
        $r_name=$row1[3];
        $r_qty=$row1[4];
        $r_rate=$row1[5];

        ?>
         <tbody>

        <tr>  
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="r_id[]" value="<?php echo $r_id ?>" PLACEHOLDER="Name" >
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_name[]" value="<?php echo $r_name ?>" PLACEHOLDER="Name"></th> 
            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_desc[]" value="" PLACEHOLDER="description"></th> 

            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_qty[]" value="<?php echo $r_qty ?>" PLACEHOLDER="QTY" ONINPUT="calculate()"></th> 

            <th><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="r_RATE[]" value="<?php echo $r_rate ?>" PLACEHOLDER="rate" ONINPUT="calculate()"></th> 
            <th></th>  

        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
```

sql query here

```
    $idCount = count($_POST["r_id"]);
for($i=0;$i<$idCount;$i++) {
$r=mysqli_query($dbcon,"UPDATE tbl_row_material set rm_user_id='" . $_SESSION['email'][$i] . "', rm_name='" . $_POST['r_name'][$i] . "', rm_qty='" . $_POST['r_qty'][$i] . "', rm_rate='" . $_POST['r_RATE'][$i] . "' WHERE rm_item_id='" . $_POST['i_no']. "' AND rm_id='". $_POST['r_id'][$i]."'");
echo $r;
}
if($r){
header('Location: ../item_master.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can try passing record id with the every field like

```
<input type="text" name="first<?php echo $id?>">
```

like this and then updating every field with respect to the id in its name.

Try and let me know, if this was helpful.

Comment: but i have given array to name attribute.dose your thing work for loop?

Comment: i have tried sending id with all the text field with corresponding ids. this was the only best solution i find in my case.   You can try and implement it now and in future if u find more better solution then change it with this solution. :)

Comment: can you edit on my code and post . becuse i am not getting what actualy this will work like

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is intended to add new table rows, but your SQL query use the `UPDATE` statement.

In your form there is only one product id and some attributes (“row material”): you pass – correctly, I suppose — only the product id to php code, but in this way, executing the query

```
UPDATE tbl_row_material SET (...) WHERE rm_item_id='$item_no'
```

you update in each loop ALL rows with `rm_item_id='$item_no'` or — if the value of `rm_item_id` doesn't exists in the database — you update nothing.

You have to use an `INSERT` query for this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_row_material
            (rm_user_id, rm_name, rm_qty, rm_rate, rm_item_id)
     VALUES ('$user', '$name', '$qty', '$rate', '$item_no');
```

The query above is only an example (I don't know your table structure): if `rm_item_id` is material id, replace its field name with the appropriate field name (item id).

If your intent is to update existing rows, you have to use `UPDATE` query with the “row material” id, not the product id.